# Upon creating a string in C, the file that I am trying to copy the contents of to this string, does so before I actually tell it to

Tags: c, file

I am trying to copy the contents of a file to a string in C.

I have written this function

```
char* read_shader_file(const char* file){
    char* src;

    int file_len = get_file_length(file);
    if(file_len == -1) return NULL;

    src = malloc(file_len+1);
    src[file_len] = '\0';


    FILE* fp = fopen(file, "rb");

    fread(src, 1, file_len, fp);

    fclose(fp);
    

    return src;
}
```

And these are the other two used.

```
int does_file_exist(const char* file){
    FILE* fp = fopen(file, "rb");
    if(fp == NULL) return false;
    fclose(fp);
    return true;
}

int get_file_length(const char* file){
    if(!does_file_exist(file)) return -1;
    FILE* fp = fopen(file, "rb");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int file_len = ftell(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return file_len;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when I remove the file opening and reading part from the function.

```
char* read_shader_file(const char* file){
    char* src;

    int file_len = get_file_length(file);
    if(file_len == -1) return NULL;

    src = malloc(file_len+1);
    src[file_len] = '\0';

    /*FILE* fp = fopen(file, "rb");

    fread(src, 1, file_len, fp);

    fclose(fp);*/
    

    return src;
}
```

'src' will still hold the files contents and I do not know why. I find it extremely weird how this is possible without me explicitly telling the program to manipulate the data in 'src'. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I could resolve this or should I just ignore it.

Comment: Have you called it more than once so you just happen to get the same block of memory you've already populated ?

Comment: I am only calling this function once.

Comment: @SmashingKrunk Can't duplicate with the code you posted. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is it really the content of the file or is it just not containing all 0 bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used calloc and ignored my problems